# Delphi Berlin lento após migrar de um projeto do Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-berlin

Eu migrei um projeto feito no Delphi Seattle para o Delphi Berlin e ficou impossível trabalhar nele pois o `autocomplete` começou a levar uns 20 segundos para mostrar alguma sugestão.

Como resolver isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para resolver este problema eu deletei o arquivo `dproj` e abri o projeto no `Berlin` usando o arquivo `dpr`. O `Berlin` criou um novo `dproj` e tudo ficou normal novamente.

Comment: Não acredito que isso seja solução, criar o `dproj` é normal em varias versões do Delphi. Agora sobre o autocomplete ficar lento, isso você arruma configurando corretamente o `CodeInsight` (por padrão vem todo zoado)

Comment: Pois é @JúniorMoreira. Pode acreditar :-) As configurações do `Code Insight` estão idênticas entre as duas versões de Delphi e meu projeto é muito menor que o seu. Quando fiz isso que descrevi voltou tudo ao normal.

Comment: Para complementar sua resposta, poderia colocar o diff entre os 2 dproj, né ?

Comment: @VictorTadashi Quem sabe outro dia. O `diff` ficou muito grande e não tenho tempo para filtrá-lo e colocar o que é relevante aqui pois tenho um projeto para entregar até sexta. Minha intenção aqui foi ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema a solucionar rapidamente.

Answer (score 2):

O `Auto Complete` deve ser configurado no `Code Insight`. O padrão configurado na instalação em projetos medianos com alguns componentes extras causa lentidão.

**Acesso o menu Tools>Options>Editor Options>Code Insight**

No projeto atual que trabalho (13 componentes extras) mais de 600 units... Fica muito lento, exatamente como você mencionou, 20 segundos ou mais se marcar:

```
Auto invoke
Auto parenthesis
History
```

O `Delay` pode causar lentidão também